# make / libc segfault in all arch linux containers

Tags: linux, arch-linux, lxc

I'm getting the following when I run `make` (from any directory with or without a makefile):

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/make 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff73050ca in strlen () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff73050ca in strlen () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7304dfe in strdup () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000418d89 in xstrdup ()
#3  0x0000000000423c33 in define_variable_in_set ()
#4  0x000000000040737b in main ()
```

I created the container with `lxc-create -n $name -t /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-archlinux`. I also have various containers I made a few months ago which are having the same problem (`make` seg faults) but are otherwise operating perfectly (`make` was working when I first made them).

Output from `lxc-checkconfig` only shows the following missing, which I believe was the same a few months ago when everything worked:

```
User namespace: missing
checkpoint restore: missing
```

This is running on a fully up-to-date x86 arch linux server. What's wrong / how can I debug this?

Edit: The error went away for 10 minutes on a couple of sessions, and I managed to compile the thing I wanted to compile, but now it's seg faulting again.

Comment: It's… funny, because I'm getting exactly the same thing in my fresh Debian SID chroot.

Comment: I haven't tested this further, but my theory now is that it has to do with running anything systemd related inside of *any* container. Namely I would reboot the server and start my containers one-by-one. Once I enabled one of the containers with an apache systemd service, *all* of the containers seg fault on `make`. Will look into further sometime in the next couple days.

Comment: Not here. Just tested a fresh Debian stretch chroot (current `testing`; systemd-based), and it works fine. So either our problems are different after all, or there was a very recent change in both distributions that results in this problem. But the fact that my stack trace is exactly the same as yours (modulo offsets) would mean it's likely it's the same bug. And the only systemd instance I'm running on this box is the host's.

Comment: I've submitted a bug against debian make package here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=812244. I noticed the bug was introduced in Debian `make 4.1`, and everything looks fine in `make 4.0`; could you try installing some earlier `make` and test?

Comment: chrooted into a container to make `make 4.0` and that version works now (while the still installed `4.1-1` segfaults).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A bug in `make 4.1`](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?43434) related to having `ttyname()` returning NULL, e.g. when `/dev/pts` is not mounted in chroot/container, results in these symptomps. Thanks to [`make` developer Paul D. Smith for fixing it](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?43434) and [Debian maintainer Manoj Srivastava for diagnosing it](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=812244).

Comment: As a side note - I just remembered / noticed that some of my containers have a bashrc with `mesg n` in them, which echos `mesg: ttyname failed: Success` every time I log in to them. So this is definitely the cause (for me).

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling base-devel by executing

```
pacman -Syu base-devel
```

Otherwise, reinstall...

Comment: Tried that to no avail / the problem occurs on newly created containers as well.